# convert mysql query return type

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-connector-python

I am developing a webapp for a school project in Flask. I am very new to python and flask.

In function "get_absence" i am executing a mysql query and i get result. (The query is working in mysql command line and giving output 15) But my result on the html page is in the form "(Decimal('15'),)". I want to extract out the number, so that i can display only 15 on the web. How can i do that?

The result from the query goes from get_absence to API function get_info and then sent to the html page "page.html". It displays on the page as "(Decimal('15'),)".

I cannot convert from tuples to integer. Anyone?

util.py:

```
def get_absence(database):
    try:
        days = []
        cur = database.cursor()
        cur.execute(queries["select SUM(dates) FROM leaves WHERE 
                            emp_id = 14"]) 
        for a in cur:
            num = a; 
        return a
    except:
        return jsonify("Internal server error"), 500
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

FLASK app.py:

```
@app.route("/get_info/", methods=["GET"])
def get_info():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.cursor(buffered=True)
    try: 
        days = get_absence(get_db() )  
        return render_template("page.html", days=days)  
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        return render_template("error.html", err = err)
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

HTML:

```
<h1>"{{ days }}" </h1>
```

When rendered, broswer shows:
"(Decimal('15'),)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` method will always return a iterator where each element is a tuple that represent a row with multiples columns.

Then in your case you just take the first element from "days" tumple:

```
days[0]
```

Then you will have a `decimal` object. You can round it in a integer doing:

```
int(days[0])
```

Also, if you are expecting a single element, then you can use `cursor.fetchone()` in order to avoid the for loop over cur object.

You can read more info [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked, i now get an output of just the number!